# How to use a different object for different environments in the controller within Ruby on Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Currently on production(Heroku), I use the below method in my Application controller to store the client's IP address in a cookie.

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :cache_ip

  def cache_ip
    cookies[:client_ip] = request.remote_ip
  end
end
```

However, the request.remote_ip method returns nil when on development (localhost:3000) and that doesn't test my feature.

I want something like this:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :cache_ip

  def cache_ip
    if ENV == production
      cookies[:client_ip] = request.remote_ip
    else
      cookies[:client_ip] = SOME.IP.ADDRESS
  end
end
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following:

```
class ApplicationController < ActionController::Base
  before_action :cache_ip

  def cache_ip
    if Rails.env.production?
      cookies[:client_ip] = request.remote_ip
    else
      cookies[:client_ip] = SOME.IP.ADDRESS
    end
  end
end
```